# Why disappear navigationBar backButtonItem? Swift4

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, back-button, large-title

I use `largeTitleBar`.
When `navigationBar.title` has character over 20 bytes (in Case iPhone SE), `backButtonItem.title` disappears. (In case iPhoneX, 22 bytes)

`navigationBar.title` becomes truncate affects this problem.
But I don't have any idea to solve this problem.

```
navigationItem.title = someText
// when navigationItem.title is truncated, backButtonItem.title disappears.
```

Comment: Thank you TheTiger!

Answer (score 0):

```
self.title = "Your TiTle Text"
var lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 40))
lbl.text = navigationItem?.title
lbl.textColor = UIColor.white
if let fontSize = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 30.0) {
    lbl.font = fontSize
}
lbl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
lbl.textAlignment = .center
navigationItem?.titleView = lbl
```

Try above code may help you.

Comment: Thank you for your code. But the problem is disappearing "backButtonItem". I can't resolve it.

Comment: I had given a static width of 200 then also it's disappearing?

Comment: Oh, I understand. You recommend using "tittleView" instead of "backButtonItem".

Comment: Yes, now you get it.

Comment: Thank you. But UILabel is not static. How can I fix it?

Comment: You can get navigation bar height and width by below code and by that you can set title text.

let navigationBarHeight: CGFloat = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height;  


let navigationBarHeight: CGFloat = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.width;

Comment: Umm. I fix "navigationItem?.titleView.frame.size.width = 20" , but titleView's width becomes larger by text length.